# Proving compositeness of $n^4+4^n$ in a different way

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have seen this question on this site but still I am asking because I have a different way but I cannot answer it anywhere.

So please don't mark it duplicate

My way:

We have two cases

1. If $n$ is even
2. If $n$ is odd

If $n$ is even then we have nothing to do, it is clearly an even number

If $n$ is odd , then I worked on the unit digits of numbers

Since n is an odd intiger it's $4^{th}$ power is positive and will end with 1

because see this $$1^4=1$$$$3^4=81$$$$7^4=2401$$$$9^4=6561$$

And also every odd power of 4 will end up with a unit digit of 4

So the sum should have unit digit $1+4=5$

And therefore is a multiple of 5

So $n^4+4^n$ is a composite number for all $n\in \mathbb N and n\gt 1$ and will have unit digit 5 only if n is odd and not a multiple of 5 .

If I am wrong anywhere,, please tell me how to correct my error and notify my error.

Comment: But what about the case $\,5\mid n,\,$ e.g.for $\,n=5\,$ it factors as $\, 17\cdot 97,\ $ and $\,n=10\,$ as $\,2^4\cdot 66161.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque:  $n=10$ is covered by the even case and indeed $2$ is a factor.  $5 \bmod 10$ is missing.

Comment: @Ross The proof does not (correctly) handle the odd multiples of $\,5.\ $ Was that not clear?

Comment: @BillDubuque:  Yes, but it did handle $n$ ending in $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You skipped the case $5^4=625$, so $5^4+4^5$ does not end in $5$.  In fact $4^5+5^4=1649=17 \cdot 97$, but your proof does not account for that.  The factors for $4^{15}+15^4=1073792449 = 29153 \cdot 36833$ are quite large, so I would not expect this approach to work easily.  Also the case $n=1$ does end in $5$, but it is prime, so you need to have $n \gt 1$.  The normal way to state this would be to talk about $n \bmod 10$.  There are only $10$ choices for $n \bmod 10$ and you have exhibited factorizations for $9$ of them.  This is a reasonable approach that solves some problems like this, but not this one.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is incomplete. It omits the possibility that the units digit of $n$
might be $5$.  For example, 
$$
5^4 + 4^5 = 1649$$ 
which does not have units digit $5$.

For $n = 10k+5$ the proof is difficult.  Look at 
$$
(15)^4 + 4^{15} = 29153\cdot 36833\\
(25)^4 + 4^{25} = 29\cdot 373 \cdot 3121 \cdot 33350257 \\
(35)^4 + 4^{35} = 34350564553\cdot 34368914633 \\
(45)^4 + 4^{45} = 53 \cdot 663863199589 \cdot 35183994603497\\
(55)^4 + 4^{55} = 36028782255016913 \cdot 36028881782917073
$$
to convince yourself that the pattern of factors is far from simple.

(BTW, $(55)^4 + 4^{55}$ does not factor into two primes that are relatively near one another; even that pattern is not true.)

To complete your proof, assume $n = 10k+5$. Then

$$
(10k+5)^4 + 4^{10k+5} = (10k+5)^4 + 4\cdot 4^{10k+4} 
= (10k+5)^4 + 4\cdot 2^{20k+8} \\
= (10k+5)^4 + 4\cdot \left(2^{5k+2} \right)^4 \\
= \left[ (10k+5)^2 + 2\cdot \left(2^{5k+2} \right)^2 
- 2\cdot (10k+5)2^{5k+2}\right] \times \\ \left[ (10k+5)^2 + 2\cdot \left(2^{5k+2} \right)^2 
+ 2\cdot (10k+5)2^{5k+2}\right] 
$$
and in cases where there are only two prime factors, these are the two. Otherwise, these factor further, but the number is still composite.

Comment: I shall edit ... Thanks for realising my mistake